# Checking a value in a basic multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This will be a quick one for most of you I'm sure, but I'm banging my head against the wall trying to teach myself multidimensional arrays.

I simply wish to check whether or not `$_FILES["Photo"]["name"]` contains empty strings, and such the code below my if statement is executed.

Currently this works, as does my else statment (not shown), however there has to be a cleaner way of writing this??

Many thanks.

```
if (empty($_FILES["Photo"]["name"][0]) && empty($_FILES["Photo"]["name"][1]) && empty($_FILES["Photo"]["name"][2])) {

    $query = "INSERT INTO lot (lotnumber, lottitle, lotdescription, datecreated, lastmodified) VALUES" . 
        "('$lotnumber', '$lottitle', '$lotdescription', NULL, NULL)";

    if (!$mysqli->query($query)) {
        echo '<p class="warning">Error executing INSERT query: (' . $mysqli->errno . ') ' . $mysqli->error . "</p>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<p class="success">The lot has been added to the directory.' . "</p>" . HTML_LINEBREAK;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing apparently wrong with that IF

Comment: Use `empty($_FILES["Photo"]["name"])` instead. It determines whether the variable is empty. either `string` or `array`.

Comment: @HashemQolami this was my logic, and it's why I'm pulling my hair out as using empty($_FILES["Photo"]["name"]) skips to my else statement even though the array is empty??

Comment: Yes, it does. check this out: http://codepad.org/ddjwXYse

Comment: bizarre, it must be something else I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have a script that counts the keys within the "name" level.

```
$count = sizeof($name_of_array->Photo->name);
```

Then in a for loop check to see if the keys are empty.

```
for($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++)
{
    if(empty($name_of_array->Photo->name[$i])
    {
        ... continue code
    }
    else
    {
        ... continue code
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried a for loop. I did try a foreach loop but that simply added 3 rows to my DB :)

Comment: @SamHolguin This is a different style. This for loop will check if the entries in the name array are empty. This will eliminate the use of hard coding name[0] with an incrementing number that only get as high as the number of keys within the name array (determined by $count). This if statement should be your old else statement. The else should be your regular code if the the names are not empty.

Comment: I'll experiment with this, it's about time I learnt for loops!! Many thanks

Comment: @SamHolguin No problem! For loops are perfect for this situation. If this works for you please accept this answer :) Good luck!

Comment: I'm experimenting with for loops....looking at your example, wouldn't this result in multiple code inserts like my foreach loop did????

Comment: Be sure to incorporate a while fetch_array within the for loop you would like to execute.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an `array_filter()`, but I don't really see the problem with what you are doing:

```
$test_array = array_filter($_FILES['Photo']['name'], function($var) {
    return empty($var);
});

if (count($test_array) === 3) {
   $query = ... // the rest of your code
}
```

Of course this assumes that there are only three elements in the array.  If you only want to check the first 3 elements, you would want to add an `array_slice()` like this:

```
$test_array = array_filter(array_slice($_FILES['Photo']['name'], 0, 3), function($var) {
    return empty($var);
});
```

Comment: I'll look into this one... haven't learnt the array_filter!! Thank you

Comment: or array_slice() for that matter